# To print the elements lying within a bin

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted my code to print only when the if condition is satisfied and then empty the array to print the next results

```
import numpy as np
r = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.000570290882095, 0.0107443912719, 0.0124509177244, 
     0.0125, 0.0125, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025,
     0.025, 0.0256640229497, 0.030566379892, 0.031401430789,
     0.0375, 0.0375, 0.0375, 0.0395298596851, 0.039780154486, 
     0.0438643740073, 0.0466295394557, 0.0480063782397, 0.05, 
     0.05, 0.068990534098, 0.0717060855612, 0.0737078626994,
     0.0783505963591, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.100794816139,
     0.110492949738, 0.1125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.137197807346, 
     0.140625, 0.147676814534, 0.149311786297, 0.15, 0.15,
     0.153789751195, 0.15653721735, 0.161158308383,
     0.165614224138,0.165804856115, 0.181477147577, 0.186858748434, 0.2]
for binStartLoad in np.arange(0, 1, 0.05): 
    k = []
    for i in range(len(r)):
        if binStartLoad >= r[i] < binStartLoad + 0.05:
            k.append(r[i])
    print k
```

Now my result is:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
 0.000570290882095, 0.0107443912719, 0.0124509177244, 0.0125, 0.0125, 
 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.0256640229497, 0.030566379892,
 0.031401430789, 0.0375, 0.0375, 0.0375, 0.0395298596851, 
 0.039780154486, 0.0438643740073, 0.0466295394557, 
 0.0480063782397, 0.05, 0.05]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.000570290882095, 0.0107443912719, 0.0124509177244, 0.0125, 
 0.0125, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.0256640229497, 
 0.030566379892, 0.031401430789, 0.0375, 0.0375, 0.0375, 
 0.0395298596851,0.039780154486, 0.0438643740073, 0.0466295394557,
 0.0480063782397, 0.05, 0.05, 0.068990534098, 0.0717060855612,
 0.0737078626994, 0.0783505963591, 0.0875, 0.0875] ans so on
```

But I wanted my results to be:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
 0.000570290882095, 0.0107443912719, 0.0124509177244, 0.0125, 0.0125, 
 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.0256640229497, 0.030566379892,
 0.031401430789, 0.0375, 0.0375, 0.0375, 0.0395298596851, 
 0.039780154486, 0.0438643740073, 0.0466295394557, 
 0.0480063782397]
[0.05, 0.05, 0.068990534098, 0.0717060855612, 0.0737078626994,
 0.0783505963591,   0.0875, 0.0875]
[0.100794816139, 0.110492949738, 0.1125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.137197807346, 
 0.140625, 0.147676814534, 0.149311786297] and so on
```

Comment: `if binStartLoad <= r[i] < binStartLoad + 0.05` you have > instead of <

Comment: and way to go for providing a running code sample

Comment: You inner loop could have been more Pythonic as -
`for value in r: ...`

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to want is to split `r` into bins with width `0.05`. A more NumPyish way of doing this could be to search the break-point indices:

```
# find the indices for the break points (0, 0.05, 0.10, .., 1.00)
bpoints = np.searchsorted(r, np.arange(0, 1+.01, 0.05), side='left')

# now the values 0.05 are at indices bpoints[0]..bpoints[1], etc.
# the resulting vectors are collected into `bins`
bins = [ r[bpoints[i]:bpoints[i+1]] for i in range(len(bpoints)-1) ]
```

Then `bins` is:

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.000570290882095, 0.0107443912719, 0.0124509177244, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.0256640229497, 0.030566379892, 0.031401430789, 0.0375, 0.0375, 0.0375, 0.0395298596851, 0.039780154486, 0.0438643740073, 0.0466295394557, 0.0480063782397], 
 [0.05, 0.05, 0.068990534098, 0.0717060855612, 0.0737078626994, 0.0783505963591, 0.0875, 0.0875], 
 [0.100794816139, 0.110492949738, 0.1125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.137197807346, 0.140625, 0.147676814534, 0.149311786297, 0.15, 0.15], 
 [0.153789751195, 0.15653721735, 0.161158308383, 0.165614224138, 0.165804856115, 0.181477147577, 0.186858748434], 
 [0.2], 
 [], 
 [], 
 [], 
 [], 
 [], 
 [], 
 [], 
 [], 
 [], 
 [], 
 [], 
 [], 
 [], 
 [], 
 []]
```

The empty lists represent the bins where there are no values. Of course, it is easy to get rid of these at the printing phase:

```
print "\n".join([ str(b) for b in bins if len(b) > 0 ])
```

However, it is usually desirable to keep the empty bins to avoid messing up with the indexing.

Please not that it is quite unpredictable where border cases (e.g., 0.15) end up due to floating point round-off errors. (Here 0.15 ends up in wrong place, because `np.arange(0,1.01,0.05)[3] > 0.15` is `True`. There is usually no such thing as "exactly equal" among floating point numbers.)